# Thunderbird write window not in focus

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, thunderbird

I'm running Thunderbird 24.3 on Debian 7 and sometimes when I click on 'Write' and it opens up a new window it's not in focus and my keystrokes are sent to the main Thunderbird screen not the new Write screen. The Windows Manager I'm using is XFCE4.

It's happening for other users of the same system and I have yet to find a pattern to reproduce this.

I've also had this happen with firefox 27.0.0 and with Thunderbird whilst using thunderbird inline conversations plugin on one of the machines which doesn't start a new window.

What I've tried and I still have the problem

- clicking on title bar
- Check error console
- Start a fresh profile (Move the .thunderbird directory and start completely fresh)

**Update**

Tried the thunderbird 24.4.0 and still have the problem.

Noticed that if I quickly hit Ctrl+n about 10 times I can re-enact the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the Window Manager's settings.
You need to modify XFCE's settings to switch the focus to the new window when a new window opens up.

In XFCE Applications Menu, open up the `Settings Manager`, then open up `Window Manager`
Go to the Focus Tab, and ensure the `Automatically give focus to newly created windows` is ticked.
Also, check to see if the focus model is on `Click to focus` or `Focus follows mouse`. If it's on `Focus follows mouse`, then ensure your mouse is over the 'write window' in Thunderbird before you start typing.

Comment: I've checked those settings and they were already ticked. Automatically give focus to newly created windows = ticked & Click to focus is ticked. This focus problem only happens with thunderbird (many times per day) & firefox (once ever)

Comment: I think this is a bug with thunderbird more than anything else